# How do I add a custom panel in Netbeans through Code?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, panels

I have a custom class that extends JPanel called Node that I want to be able to add to panel MainPanel through code, but the Nodes are not appearing. It works fine with drag and drop, but I want to add more Nodes during runtime.

Comment: Show us some codes so we can able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to add more Nodes during runtime.

When adding components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();  
panel.repaint();
```

You need to invoke the layout manager to the component has a size and location otherwise the size is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.